# Firebase DB rules. Limit write access by phone number

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules

I am using Firebase realtime datababase to implement synchronized DB for my applications on different platforms. 
I need the way to allow everyone read from the database.
Only users authenticated by phone number, and if this number is in admins list, will be able to write to database. i didnt find a way to get phone number from "auth" object in DB rules.
Any help will be gratefully appreciated!

Here is DB Structure and rules I am using right now.

```
{
  "admins" : {
    "+97254000000" : {
      "name" : "Pirate Pirate",
      ...
    }
  },
  "mesages" : {
    "msg1" : {
      "orderTimestamp" : 1526916646226,
      "txt" : "some message"
    },
    "msg2" : {
      "orderTimestamp" : 1526916643522,
      "txt" : "some message"
    },
    "msg3" : {
      "orderTimestamp" : 1526916486229,
      "txt" : "some message"
    }
  }
}
// Database Rules
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After few hours of searching, i took a brake for a coffee, and found answer right away :)

Firebase database security rules comes with ["auth"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables) object that contain almost everything you ever need to check identity of the user.(phone number, email, name etc.)
So all information that I was looking for is placed in ["auth.token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables)" part.

New rules looks like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "root.child('admins').child(auth.token.phone_number).exists()"      
  }
}
```